Telegram bot doesn't work anymore. RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.send_message' was never awaited
My telegram bot doesn't send messages anymore. I get this error: "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.send_message' was never awaited".
from telegram import Bot

bot_token = 'xxx'

chat_id = 'xxx'   
message = 'TEST'

bot = Bot(token=bot_token)

bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)


so the same exact code worked before?

yes, always worked

I'm assuming that you're using the python-telegram-bot package?
If so, according to the python-telegram-bot documentation, Bot.send_message is an async function. This means that when calling it, you have two options:

asyncio.run(...), which can be used anywhere, or
The await keyword, which can only be used inside another async function.

Solution 1: using asyncio.run
Try changing this line...
bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)

...to this:
asyncio.run(bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message))

and add this import to the top of the file:
import asyncio

Your final code should look like this:
import asyncio
from telegram import Bot

bot_token = 'xxx'

chat_id = 'xxx'   
message = 'TEST'

bot = Bot(token=bot_token)

asyncio.run(bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message))

Solution 2: using await
If you decide to use await, you will need to wrap your code inside an async function, and then call that function with asyncio.run(...). So this:
bot_token = 'xxx'

chat_id = 'xxx'   
message = 'TEST'

bot = Bot(token=bot_token)

bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)

becomes this:
async def run_bot():
    bot_token = 'xxx'

    chat_id = 'xxx'   
    message = 'TEST'

    bot = Bot(token=bot_token)

    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)

Note the use of async def: this marks the function as being async.
Now that we have a single async function to call, we are left with the same problem as before: we need to call an async function at the top-level of our script. This can be solved with method 1. This gives us:
improt asyncio
from telegram imrt Bot

async def run_bot():
    bot_token = 'xxx'

    chat_id = 'xxx'   
    message = 'TEST'

    bot = Bot(token=bot_token)

    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)

if __name__ == '__main__': # <-- Only run the code if this is the main file that is being run.
    asyncio.run(run_bot())

I only noted this method in this case because it's a good way to encapsulate all the functionality of a program, even if the solution does kind of repeat the problem. Using solution 1 alone is more convenient for this case.

I get this error: "SyntaxError: 'await' outside function"

but how did it work in the past? If that would be the solution, then telegram must have changed something in the way bots work

@Cincinnatus I don't know much about python-telegram-bot specifically, but I've used pycord (previously discord.py) in the past, and they rewrote a bunch of stuff in that library. Not sure if it was to make things async, but my point is that this is probably what the python-telegram-bot developers have done (or are doing). Could be wrong as I'm not sure...

@AngelaArgentieri Apologies, I had missed an important detail (I rushed the answer initially). See my edited answer.
